# PHP- How to create a text file in network shared folder

Tags: php, file, file-io

Can someone pls help me on how to create  a text file in network shared folder. The shared folder has username and password.
Many thanks!
here my code

```
<?php
system('net use \\192.168.*.*\folder$ password/user:username');
$dir = "\\192.168.*.*\folder$";
if (is_dir($dir)) 
{
    if ($dh = opendir($dir))        
        print "able to access directory tree.";       
}
else {   print "not access tree.";}
?>
```

Comment: Found that php somehow couldn't read  folder$ (hidden folder). Removed $ (made it visible) and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that php somehow couldn't read folder$ (hidden folder). Removed $ (made it visible) and worked.

```
<?php
//system('net use \\192.168.*.*\folder$ password/user:username');
$dir = "\\\\192.168.*.*\\folder";
if (is_dir($dir)) 
{
    if ($dh = opendir($dir))        
        print "able to access directory tree.";       
}
else {   print "not access tree.";}
?>
```